# htaccess - Rewrite two random segments with one static

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

Hello I try to achive to rewrite URLs via htacces from old path

```
https://example.com/staticword-randomword/random-words/target.php
```

to new path

```
https://example.com/new/target.php
```

I've tried to manage this with this Rewrite command:

```
RewriteRule ^staticword(.*)/(.*)/ new/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Unfortunatelly I'm not very well with these rewrite commands and the rewrites the URLs to

```
https://example.com/new/-randomword/random-words/
```

Could someone point me to the solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is not correct and `.*` is greedy in nature.

You can use this redirect rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^staticword-[^/]*/[^/]*/([^/]+)/?$ /new/$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

Make sure to use a new browser for testing this change to avoid old browser cache.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for my bad regex skills this is a sealed book for me. Your rewrite rule works very well, except of the typo between NC and NE, replaced it with a comma.